# Error opening .jpg images with readJPEG{jpeg} in R

Tags: r, image

I looked for examples on-line to understand the syntax of this function, but there aren't a lot of entry-level posts. The one that keeps on repeating is the example in the package documentation: `img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))`.

I don't know how to extrapolate this to reading a file from my computer R directory: `"C:/Users/p/Documents/R"`, but I tried unsuccessfully lines like:

```
img <- readJPEG(system.file("/Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg", package="jpeg"))
Error in readJPEG(system.file("/Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg", package = "jpeg")) : 
  unable to open
```

A promising alternative packages, `{ReadImages}`, is no longer available in the CRAN.

Can I get some help with the syntax of this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is being caused by `system.file`, which is unnecessary. Just take it out; it should work fine just as

```
img <- readJPEG("/Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg")
```

If you need to expand a path, or otherwise don't feel like typing one out, you can replace `system.file` with `normalizePath`:

```
img <- readJPEG(normalizePath("~/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg"))
```

Comment: I'm getting this: `img <- readJPEG("/Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg")
Error in readJPEG("/Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg") : 
  unable to open /Users/p/Documents/R/leaf.jpeg`

Comment: Weird, it works for me. I assume you double-checked your path? Have you tried with another image? You might try moving the image to your working directory (or set your working directory to that of the image) and just use `readJPEG('leaf.jpeg')` in case it's a weird path thing.

Comment: I made sure that the file was in the R directory. Is there any other way of checking the path?

Comment: Just run `normalizePath('leaf.jpeg')` by itself, and if it returns a full path you're fine. If you're in RStudio (and probably some other editors), if you press tab while partway through a path, it should autocomplete the folder/document name, which guarantees it's accurate, too.

Comment: It worked by just changing ".jpeg" to "jpg"! Thanks!

Comment: It's always the little things. Happy hacking!